# Yum email notification when new tomcat update is available?

Tags: linux, tomcat, yum

I have decided to exclude tomcat from yum auto updates. I would however like to know when new updates are available so I can review their worth. I see that you can set yum to send email notification when updates to packages are available. But is there any way to filter it such that I will only receive an email when an update is available for tomcat?

Or, failing that, anyone know of somewhere I can subscribe to receive this update info for tomcat?

Cheers,

Chris

PS. Serverfault is the right for this post, as opposed to Superuser, for example???

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the exclude list at runtime via `--disableexcludes=everything` switch.

so you can check for tomcat update in this way for instance:

`yum check-update --disableexcludes=everything | grep tomcat | mail ....`

Answer (score 1):

Fedora, RHEL, and CentOS each have mailing lists dedicated to announcing new package releases.